# Is there a way to use the Hot Reload functionality for XAML in a configuration other than Debug?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, configuration

Does anyone happen to have an idea what configuration setting needs to be changed so that my WPF project's XAML can be edited during debugging?

I've run into this issue:

- Create a blank WPF project
- Add a simple button
- Debug app in the `Debug` Configuration
- Change colour of button
- Changes reflected

If I do the *same* thing but change the configuration to be `Debug-New` and run the app up, I get `Hot Reload Unavailable`

[image: xaml hot reload unavailable]

I am using Visual Studio 2019 v16.6.2.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make the ***Hot Reload available***: open **Debug** > **Options** > **General**. Make sure that both options, **Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML** and **Enable XAML Hot Reload** are selected.
[image]

Update

Please remove your Debug-New and create a new Debug-New with selecting **Debug** for *Copy setting from*

[image]

**Update 2**

Please make sure that you choose the proper Configuration for your project.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, in my settings all those options are enabled but still no dice :(

Comment: Yep did that too. Still got the same problem. It only seems to work in the default Debug mode. Any others, it's just failing to work.

Comment: Please check your configuration for your project, and I update my answer again for you.

Comment: I've followed all the steps as you've mentioned and it's the normal process I follow anyway but it doesn't seem to fix anything. Are you also using Visual Studio 2019 v16.6.2? Could be a VS bug.

Comment: It is maybe, my VS is 16.2.0.

Comment: If you're using a custom build configuration (not `Debug`) you have to add a line to the .csproj that will enable hot reload: `<XamlDebuggingInformation>True</XamlDebuggingInformation>`. I'm using a custom config with a name different than `Debug` and this fixed the problem for me, hot reload is working again. My csproj entry looks like:```<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='MyCustomDebug'">
    <XamlDebuggingInformation>True</XamlDebuggingInformation>
</PropertyGroup>```

Comment: Hot relad works for blazor wasm only in start without debugging. For me in wpf it also only worked in start without debugging...